# how to convert any logical query into mongodb query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, algorithm, mongodb

i have query like this:

```
var query='(("email=mk@gmailcom"|"ame=mk")&("email=mk1@gmailcom"|"nam=mk1"))&code=123';
```

but this may vary. how to convert this type of query into mongodb query syntax like this :

```
 { $and: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> } , ... , { <expressionN> } ] }
```

we need a library or algorithm by which we can convert any logical query into mongodb query. is there any library or algorithm ?

Comment: How is this related to angularjs?

Comment: What language is your query in?

Comment: query is a string, but i have to convert it in mongodb query.i am using angular for front end and node for backend

Comment: Your first problem will be two parse the string into some kind of AST. Transforming that into a MongoDB query will be easy - but the parsing part isn't MongoDB related. Maybe try rephrasing and retagging the question to see if someone has a parser library they can recommend?